# How to create a patch for ASP.net app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, patch

Every time I want to update my asp app  I create a new publish, remove the app from IIS and then re-install the new version. Is there a better way to update my app when something in code changes ?

Comment: How are you publishing?

Comment: From VS where it creates a zipped package to be deployed on IIS

Comment: you only need to replace what's in the bin dir

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: Lets say I am trying to optimize the process of deploying changes as much as possible

Comment: @Cemre This does not answer my question. What is the metric you're using? Is it minimizing downtime? Is it minimizing the amount of bytes transferred to the server? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I see, well downtime is one thing of course but my main goal is to smoothen the process by automatizing it as much as possible. Uninstalling and reinstalling  the app when a line of code changes just doesnt seem right

Comment: Well if you look at the "Publish" menu in Visual Studio, you'll see many more options for different publish types....perhaps you should start there.

Comment: ASP.NET web applications are, for the most part, "xcopy-deployable", so I don't get what are you reinstalling. If you want to really automate deploymens, you'll have to invest into getting build server up and running, so that every commit to release branch is automagically deployed to production. Zero-downtime deployments require much more sophisticated setups involving load balancer and at least two web servers.